# ArcGIS 5km buffer output is very small and square?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, arcgis-10.5

This is part of a task for an intro to ArcGIS class, and I'm super stuck.
I need to create buffers of 5, 10, 15, 20km from a centrepoint, to investigate vegetation changes over different years.

In the buffer panel, I input the `centrepoint.shp` from the dropdown list, and chose a linear distance of 5000m. When I apply it, the buffer is created but I can't see it. Using 'zoom to layer' the scale become `1:1.49`, and my buffer appears as a square shape instead of a round one. My features are all set to `WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_38N` if that helps.

Here is an image gallery of some of my data and how the buffer layer is appearing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmkBX.jpg

Update: My professor tried to recreate this on his own software and was unable, and said that based on the data in my layers this issue shouldn't have been occurring and it may be an issue in my software itself. I have a new download link from IT and will try again on fresh software.

Comment: Welcome to the GIS SE. It might be worthwhile posting some pictures of the data and data view? It helps contextualise the question and may get a better response. Can you confirm that the "centrpoints.shp" is definitely projected in UTM 38N? ArcMap can show mixed coordinates in a data view, and your data may not be in the UTM coordinate system.

Comment: @KeaganAllan here's a screengrab of what the coords look like in properties https://imgur.com/a/T0ZLRnI
The system I chose was a custom one that was included in the other shapefiles in the data package, so I set all the un-projected files to this. I also tried using the Projected dropdown menus to find the same coord system and have the same thing happening when I put my files in this system.

Comment: I just want to update, my professor had a look and determined that the buffer outputs I was getting should not be occurring, and it's most likely a problem in my software.

Comment: Could you post pics of you data, the square buffer is definitely not something Arc produces from points. You may need to confirm that the unprojected files you changed are in fact in that system. 

As an aside, instead of posting pictures / screen grabs in the comments, could you edit your question to include them. It makes it easier for other people to see your problem and answer it, or in the future someone may have a similar issue and want to see the solution. It is hard trawling through the comments section to see answers / updates.

Comment: @KeaganAllan I've updated the post with a new imgur link and included some extra pictures there. Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: My gut feeling is that there is something corrupt with the data, as @KeaganAllan says it should be a circular result not square, or there is some odd environment settings. Can you provide a download link to the data?

Comment: I'm also wondering about environment settings like @Hornbydd said. Maybe something with processing extent. Given how 'zoomed-in' the scale is, that small square makes me think 'raster pixel'. It doesn't look like you have any raster layers in your data frame, but presumably those landcover layers were vectorized from a raster. Perhaps one of those layers has a very small feature selected and it is limiting the extent of the buffer?

Comment: Another thought, I noticed your workspace folder (Desktop\Assignment 1 data) has spaces in the name. Sometimes Arc has problems handling paths with spaces, so I try to use underscores instead. Probably not the issue in this case, but may be something to try (and also consider as a best practice)

Comment: @Nick thanks for the tip!